# Is there any way to pass arguments for pig script without using -param

Tags: arguments, apache-pig

I am new to pig, is there any way to pass arguments for pig script without using -param like unix. I want to access the values as Stream a stream using $1 and $2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Unix, we can't access parameters using $1, $2 notations. Unless the param key name is 1, 2 etc..

Ref : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#param_sub

To send individual parameters using -param or -p

```
pig -p fn=Raj -p ln=Kumar -f display_name.pig
```

Other alternative is to define all key value pairs in a parameter file.

```
names.cfg
---------
fn=Raj
ln=Kumar
```

To use the file use -m or -param_file

```
pig -m names.cfg -f display_name.pig
```

Comment: Thanks Murali for your response. But here it will stick us to use the same variable to load rt. Is there any way to load the runtime variable load. If Pig supports the $1, $2 notation then we can load the runtime variable also

Comment: @logeshwaran : You can invoke pig script from shell script and pass values  to the pig script dynamically. In the above script you can pass fn and ln values dynamically from shell script.